# Hide list under ul using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-selectors, telerik-mvc

I was trying to hide HTML list using the Jquery. Please tell me the suggestion where i am doing wrong.

This is the rendered code:

```
<div id="TabStrip_3" class="t-widget t-tabstrip t-header">
    <ul class="t-reset t-tabstrip-items">
        <li class="t-item t-state-default t-state-active">
            <a class="t-link" href="#TabStrip_3-1">Details</a>
        </li>
        <li id="3" class="t-item t-state-default">
            <a class="t-link" href="/Acquisition/PoDetails/Create/3">Create New Detail</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need to hide the li using its Id. Please help for this.

Thanks,

Comment: You haven't posted your jQuery code what you have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) you can't start `id` attribute with number.

To hide all `li` under particular element use:

```
$('#TabStrip_3').find('li').hide()​
```

In your case you should change your `id` and then you could hide it simply:

```
$('#my-li-id').hide()
```

Comment: The rule that `id` attribute must start with a letter is not valid in HTML5 anymore. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: After Appending the Letter with id(number) it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#3').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery filter. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CPcBY/)

```
var tlen = $("#TabStrip_3 ul.t-reset li").length;
$("#TabStrip_3 ul.t-reset li").filter(function(index){

 return tlen-index < 4;
}).hide();​
```

Comment: I need to hide only the list with id 3. I mean that conditionally deleting the second list with its id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TabStrip_3 li').hide()​
```

This hides all the lis in the div.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to only hide list with id '3', you may use jquery [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
$('#3').hide();​
```

**Fiddle Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/j5wAp/